# DropDownListFor get selected item value as parameter to controller

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, linq, html.dropdownlistfor

**Problem** 
I want my Html form to pass the value of the selected DropDownListFor to the controller but I can't figure out why the controller is not taking any value.
Im sending the value to the controller and trying to do some code with the selected value each time the user selects something but i can't manahe myselft to do it.

**View**

```html
@Html.DropDownList("Fechas", "Todas")
    <div id="target">
    </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
 $('#Fechas').on('change', function () {
                   dataTable.columns('.fechas').search(this.value).draw();
                   var datafecha = $(this).val();

                });

                $("#Fechas").change(function () {
                    var dateSelected = $("select option:selected").first().text();
                    $.get('@Url.Action("Index")',
                        { id: dateSelected }, function (data) {
                            $("#target").html(data);
                        });
                });
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index(string id)
    {

        var db = Context();



        string dateday;
        string lines;
        List<string> listItem2 = new List<string>();
        List<string> listadesumas = new List<string>();

        foreach (var item in db.Pos.Select(l => l.Fecha).Distinct())
        {
            dateday = Convert.ToString(item);
            lines = dateday.Split(' ')[0];
            listItem2.Add(lines);
        }
        var fechas = new SelectList(listItem2.ToList());
        ViewBag.Fechas = fechas;

        ////////////-------------------/////////////

       if (id == //SOMETHING)
{
    // To do code comes here, which takes selectGroup as parameter
}

        ////////////_----------------------////////////

        return View("~/Views/HomePos/Index.cshtml",db.Pos.ToList());
    }
```

So how can i get my selected id as a parameter to use it in my controler and change data on the view? im not fully atached to javascript so if you have other approaches i will appreciate any help

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in your javascript, is dateSelected actually populated with the value?

Comment: what selectGroup  refers to in your controller? also you don't seem to use the id variable anywhere in the controller

Comment: its not entering the javascript the value is empty @SouhaiebBesbes